# How to create data states in grafana with mysql?

Tags: grafana

I have a grafana dashboard connected to mysql, my question is how can I create a status of the data that is selected in a Query, for example I have a diseases table that keeps track of all the people who got measles in the last week :

```
SELECT Tuberculosis, last_update
FROM indicadores_de_salud 
WHERE id_municipio = 1 
ORDER BY last_update desc;
```

With this I want to make a kind of condition, for example, if the result of the query is from 0 to 5 cases of measles, the status should be normal and a green color will appear on the graph, if it is from 5 to 10 it should show a warning status, and if it is greater than 10, it shows an alert status.

I have searched the internet for several hours but I only find outdated information, any help is appreciated in advance

This is the model of the MySQL tables

[image]

Each "indicador_de_salud" table has a table called "info_municipio" that stores the records of patients and is consulted through the "last_update" field.

Query result:

[image]

Comment: `GROUP BY last_update` means *"take all the rows which share the exact same value in last_update, and aggregate them to a single output row"*. This would give one output row per distinct value in `last_update` present in the input data. I don't think that's what you're trying to do. Pleae create a demonstration sample data set, and then show the results you'd want from that data. *(More details on why this is advised can be found here; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952))*

Comment: @MatBailie I think my question is more focused on the grafana tool than mysql, but if you think a minimal reproducible example might be useful, I've just added it,

Comment: If you've solved the mysql aspect, please remove the mysql tag, and make it explicitly about grafana.